# rails helper to give a upload file a unique name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys
I'm now working on a project that require upload a lot of videos, Does rails have this helper can handle this, like the address of youtube video :

> www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYUhtPV_Lk4

Thanks

Comment: You want to upload a lot of YouTube video URLs?

Comment: let's me explain, my project is download youtube video and upload to my server, become youtube is banned from my country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using activerecord to model the files or are they simply flat files somewhere?

if you have a model like UploadedFile << ActiveRecord::Base for each file you can just use the id of the model or if you want a string you can hash it with some string added as salt.

```
irb(main):021:0> file_id = 1
=> 1
irb(main):022:0> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('SomeRandomString' + file_id.to_s)
=> "70f5eedc8d4f02fd8f5d4e09ca8925c2f8d6b942"
```

if you are simply keeping them as flat files on the system, you can hash their path+filename to create a unique string.

```
irb(main):016:0> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest '/home/bob/somefile.mp4'
=> "204a038eddff90637c529af7003e77d600428271"
```

and you can always add in a timestamp of the current time and a random number to prevent dupes.

Comment: Thanks, but does SHA1 is the only choice? for a file name, I think it need to be shorter

Comment: you can actually just take a part of the sha1, but the less you take the more likely they are to collide (two different files giving same hash)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a random string like this and use it as the file name:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s) # => 800b262b59296b660a4f73e23580809143ed8846
```

Comment: Thanks Zabba, can I make it shorter?

Comment: I suppose you could use something like this (it *should* generate a unique number, but who knows for sure :) `Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+(rand * 1000000).round.to_s` => `20101221022720522543`

Answer (score 0):

> SecureRandom.uuid generates a v4 random UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier)
>
> It doesn't contain meaningful
>
> information such as MAC address, time, etc.
>   See RFC 4122 for
>   details of UUID.

```
SecureRandom::uuid
```